# Can I use road shifters with Linkglide cassette?

Tags: shimano, shifter, compatibility, linkglide, cues

We know that road shifters for CUES may be coming in the future. What's interesting is that CUES derailleurs feature a tension adjuster, which is meaningful. In general, it seems like the new groupset will replace low-budget range, both for road and mountain biking, even including Deore or Tiagra. More so, I would say we are mistaken that it's meant mostly for e-bikes. Clearly, we can compare it's features to mountain biking or touring groupsets right now. E.g. The diffrence between Deore and Cues casette is only about 100g even though it's thicker. More expensive LG700 casette weights just about 600g. According to Shimano, the U8000 is replacement for the trekking T8000 groupset, U6000 derailleur looks just like M5100 (

), etc.

Linkglide's pull ratio is 1:1, and it pulls about 3.7mm of cable.
Does this mean that there is potential for older shifters to shine? What about drop bar shifters used for gravel and touring? What is real LG compatibility?

Comment: As I said, it looks like LG will replace all low-budget groupsets that we use for touring no matter what reviews will say, they will be out of production. Shimano claims that 40% of all bikes sold worldwide over the next two years will come fitted with CUES components which means that HUGE drop of those parts coming soon.

Answer (score 2):

Something useful I discovered in the hunt for a thumb shifter that works with linkglide:

I measured how much cable my 11s linkglide Deore XT trigger shifter pulls per indexed click: 3.58mm (that’s purely shifter cable movement not derailleur movement),

I then measured how much cable my new “SRAM Compatible” 11s Microshift bar end shifter pulls per indexed click: 3.58mm

(I measured 10 clicks of pull on each and divided by 10; the XT pull was measured on the bike, in both directions; Mititoyo digital vernier calipers)

My 1x mid-drive e-bike has the 11s XT 11-50T linkglide cassettte & XT linkglide derailleur; wolf tooth 48T chainring; 11s XT trigger shifter. I’ve put the Microshift shifter onto a Pauls Thumbie and plan swap out the XT trigger shifter for the thumb shifter.

But I could see it useful as a bar end shifter on a drop bar 1x11s Linkglide gravel bike.

Comment: Thanks to have reported it! It would also be very useful for a 2x11 gravel bike: the U8000 would also be a very good transmission for a gravel (46-31 front, 11-45 rear).

Comment: That is super useful information, thanks. Sounds like a setup we'll see more of in the future.

Answer (score 1):

At this time, I haven't found any real tests or opinions on the creative usage of CUES, mainly because it's not widely available yet. Brands still getting rid of the pandemic stock. If we're discussing our current (late 2023) situation, we have a few interesting options to test and look closer:

**SRAM second most popular standard is the 1:1.**

- MTB RD 9s,10s https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-x7-a1
- MTB RD 10s https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-gx-t21-a1
- ROAD RD 10s https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-apx-a1
- ROAD RD 11s https://www.sram.com/en/sram/models/rd-riv-b1

Details: https://bike.bikegremlin.com/1278/bicycle-rear-derailleur-compatibility/

**Friction** **shifters**, which also can be used on drop-bar bikes, solve the problem in the blink of an eye, because most of the time they don't care what pull ratio you have. Most-likely every friction shifter that is meant for cassette in HG standard has potential. https://nsmb.com/articles/shimano-inadvertently-upgrades-friction-shifting/

We can also expect Microshift and others to fill the holes in the future.

Comment: You mention the question that LinkGlide uses a 1:1 actuation ratio with 3.7 mm of cable pull. Then in this answer you mention that SRAM also uses 1:1 actuation, but you don’t mention the cable pull. Do SRAM shifters pull 3.7 mm of cable?